# How do I declare the variable "i" and "remove" in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-develop

```
public function remove(u:Unit)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i)

}
```

The errors are:

```
1008: variable 'i' has no type declaration
1008: return value for function 'remove' has no type declaration
```

Comment: How do I declare the variable "i" and "remove"?

Comment: -1, poorly written question and doesn't belong to Game Development. Post it on http://stackoverflow.com/ and with more detail.

Comment: Ok, I will do that ...

Answer (score 1):

You have no braces after your for-loop declaration.

```
public function remove(u:Unit)
{
     for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     {}
}
```

Also, perhaps size is not defined.

Please, in future use stackoverflow.com for pure programming type questions such as this.

Comment: / To put braces did not work ... How do I declare size?                 In the future I will put my programming questions on stackoverflow.com, thanks ...